# 'Shall we talk later', can we put a question mark after this?

Tags: shall-future, shall-will

This is not a direct question? Can we put '?' at the end of 'shall we talk later'?

Comment: This is a direct question in form, so you can certainly put a '?' after it. Why don't you think you can?

Comment: It's a direct question, and a question mark at the end is standard.

Answer (score 2):

This is a direct question, so you absolutely can, and in fact must, end it with a question mark. There are some cases where it is a little softer. For example:

> Perhaps we can talk later.

This is kind of half way between a question and a statement. It is grammatically a declarative statement, so should not have a question mark, but it has a questioning subtext to it. You'd expect the response to be "Yes we can.", or "No I am busy." In fact, failure to answer would be pregnant. The failure to answer would be quite similar to the failure to answer the literal question you posed.

BTW, your tag was shall-will, however my answer would be the same irrespective of your use of either verb here. "Shall we talk later?" and "Will we talk later?" although different in meaning, are both still questions.

Comment: Note that a question mark is certainly permitted in your example above.  The question mark would indicate that the intonation implied a question.

Comment: @HotLicks we do not use a rising intonation for indirect questions. I wonder who she is dating is not said with a rising intonation. nor is perhaps we can talk later, unless used in response to the very same phrase.

Comment: @green_ideas - Sez who??

Comment: @green_ideas: We don't use rising intonations for questions of the form *"I wonder whether we could meet on Thursday."* For other forms, including the one above? Certainly.